# ui dialog box (like popup msgbox) on MVC View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Insert button on the View Page.
On this Insert Button click, there is controller Action Method (InsertUser) that inserts record.

After successful insert i want to diplay the user like a MsgBox that ("Record successfully inserted") using any plugins...etc.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a modal dialogue, or just a notification message?

The simplest way to do it is to stick your confirmation message into e.g. TempData["ConfirmationMessage"] and have something in your master page render the contents of that if it exists.

If you want a proper modal dialogue you'll need Javascript. Check out jQuery UI for probably the easiest one:- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog - you can use the same idea (something in your master page renders the confirmation message), then on the document ready event you have jQuery turn it into a dialogue.

Comment: I need a Modal Dialogue Message as in 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

Comment: Then you'll probably want to use jQuery UI. :)

Answer (score 0):

I posted a huge answer on modal windows with mvc here:
[Simple ASP.NET MVC CRUD views opening/closing in JavaScript UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog/1844916#1844916)

It outlines modal windows for forms but will probably get you 90% there.  Instead of a form you'd just be retrieving some text.