# Good example / tutorial of adding and editing a data row in a lightbox using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, lightbox

Im looking for a good example or tutorial which demonstrates adding and editing a data row (presented in a HTML Table) in a light box using ASP.NET MVC?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:  [Simple ASP.NET MVC CRUD views opening/closing in JavaScript UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog/1844916#1844916)