# How can I close one jQuery UI Dialog and focus on another?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

After my call to $.ajax(), all UI Dialogs currently close and the page appears to do a full postback as per firebug--this is not what I want. I want the List ** UI Dialog** (read: partial view) visible, then the "Create" button is pressed to open another UI dialog for creating an address. I want to **ajax post** the data (preferably strongly-typed, though I couldn't figure out how to do that, hence the ugly `data:` value in the &.ajax call), close the create address dialog and **refresh** the List dialog--never "returning" to the initial standard view before List was opened.

in the Create partial view:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="createaddress(<%= ViewData["ProfileID"] %>); return false;" />
```

in the List partial view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createaddress(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Address/Create/" + id,
            data: "address1=" + document.getElementById('Address1').val() + "&address2=" + document.getElementById('Address2').val() +
                "&city=" + document.getElementById('City').val() + "&state=" + document.getElementById('State').val() + "&zip=" + document.getElementById('Zip').val() +
                "&zipplus=" + document.getElementById('ZipPlus').val(),
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#dialog-address-create").dialog('close');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[jfar's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog) does not have sufficient jQuery UI Dialog code to do what I want, and I think his post involved standard views where I am using partial views--but I am using his ModalViewEngine class.

Also, subsequent clicks on Create produce a jQuery UI Dialog with old values in my textboxes--how do I reset these?

Comment: For the `data` piece, it's like this: `{ address1: $('#Address1').val(), address2: $('#Address2').val() }`, though `$("#myFormID").serialize()` may also do what you're after.

Comment: David, i think you should firstly refactor your code to use unobtrusive javascript, rather than tying directly on the onclick event of your input. i know this is not the cuase of your issue but you'll be asking for issues further down stream using this methodology, especially if you have multiple events firing in a variety of ways (i.e. by class and/or by id). just my advice from experience in the past... also, as per nick's comment, use the jQuery notation, rather than getElementById. it doesn't make any difference to the result but is actually simpler to use once you get going with it.

Comment: @Nick: Good call--but that doesn't make the script much easier to write when I implement this for other models. I was hoping for a strongly-typed way to submit a form to `public ActionResult Create(Address address) { /* validate, insert, return View()???? */ }`

Comment: @jim: I'm trying to implement this for one of my models (Address) and I'll worry about cleaning everything up later. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I don't see how "strongly typed" is possible, given that HTTP of necessity forces coercion of all parameter values to strings.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some way to pass JSON and receive it as a strongly typed view model in the action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around viewdata:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" 
    onclick="createaddress('<%= ViewData["ProfileID"] %>'); return false;" />
```

Or even better unobtrusively:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("create", "address", new { id = ViewData["ProfileID"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "theForm" })) { %>
    <!-- some input fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
<% } %>
```

And then attach to the submit event of the form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#theForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#dialog-address-create").dialog('close');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It turns out I was still including jfar's ModalViewEngine in my project--which for some reason was doing a full postback. Anyway, this is slicker--I never thought of serializing the entire form. To read it on the server side, would I need to specify `type: 'json'` and read the FormCollection parameter in my action method?

Comment: No, you don't need to specify `type: 'json'`. Serializing the form simply sends the form values in the POST request body as if it was a normal request.