# Edit or Add new Item from the list view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create view which will show list of products as table. And in the first column of that table will be some buttons(Remove and edit). I want to show the informations details for users to modify selected product when edit button is clicked. Does anybody has a solution ? Actually I've tried some, but I'm looking for the best one.

Comment: for happy ending - actually implementing this - answer would be quite lengthy. Unfortunately - haven't time to help You atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Maybe someone has problem with partial views. I advise this 2 links

[ASP.NET-MVC-is-not-all-about-Linq-to-SQL](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/132/ASP.NET-MVC-is-not-all-about-Linq-to-SQL)

[Validating-the-Contact-Manager-with-MVC-2.0-And-VS-2010](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/134/Validating-the-Contact-Manager-with-MVC-2.0-And-VS-2010)

Answer (score 4):

[Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)
 by Steve Sanderson is a really great example of how to make this happen.

Update: I wrote a quite lengthy explanation of how to create modal edit popups.  Check this answer out: [Simple ASP.NET MVC CRUD views opening/closing in JavaScript UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog/1844916#1844916)

Comment: i have found it at. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/132/ASP.NET-MVC-is-not-all-about-Linq-to-SQL. thanks to everyone