# Automatically render a partial when the request is sent through ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial

I'm trying to figure out how I can automatically render a view as a partial (no master page) when the request is made through ajax.

What I want to avoid is to use the following code in every controller method that can return ajax (since that's not very DRY):

```
return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(model) : View(model)
```

My first thought was to add the check into my base controller in the `View` method. But the view method returns a `View` (which `PartialView` do not inherit). So that failed.

My next attempt was to try to make the check in my custom razor view engine and simple remove the master page if it's a ajax request. But that failed too.

What I can do is to create a new method `ViewOrPartial` which contains the check and return a result accordingly.

How would you have done it?

Comment: Please note: On a project with a large number of Ajax requests, I randomly got Ajax requests from mobile browsers that had `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` returning false!!! I had to add a querystring parameter (like `partial=1`) to my requests to be on the safe side. Without it it would sometimes render entire pages into a child element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about putting the following:

```
@{
    Layout = !Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" : null;
}
```

in your `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` and in your controller action simply returning a view:

```
return View(model);
```

All razor views use `_ViewStart.cshtml`. This is where the master page is specified. So by making this change all views automatically will apply the master page only conditionally if the request was not an AJAX request. Pretty DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I outline how to do this here:
[Simple ASP.NET MVC CRUD views opening/closing in JavaScript UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog/1844916#1844916)

Comment: I've tried that, but IsAjaxRequest() was always false in the view engine. I have no idea why.

Comment: Include an abstract in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to load it via jQuery: [Using jQuery ajax to load a partial view in ASP.NET MVC and then retrieve the input on the server again](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingJQueryAjaxToLoadAPartialViewInASPNETMVC2AndThenRetrieveTheInputOnTheServerAgain.aspx).

Comment: You have not understood my question. I'm using jquery to convert all links with "ajax" in the classname to ajax requests. That part is working like it should. And the action is being called by the ajax request. I don't want to use something like `return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(model) : View(model)` in all actions that can be called either normally or through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I found in practice that `IsAjaxRequest` is not 100% reliable.

With loads of requests from a mobile device it would occasionally return `false` on an Ajax call.

I wound up adding a query string parameter (e.g. partial=1) to my Ajax requests to ensure the controller was not fooled. This was around MVC 4 so may have been corrected since then, but I can't afford to take a chance.

### In my base controller (inherited by all my controllers) I added this:

```
public bool IsPartialPageRequest
{
    get
    {
        return Request.IsAjaxRequest() || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["partial"]);
    }
}
```

### In the controllers I then have something like:

```
    if (!base.IsPartialPageRequest)
    {
        ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
```

### And finally in my views I have:

```
@{
    Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}
```

I ensure I always add `&partial=1` to my Ajax requests (just in case) and it has been 100% reliable since.