# Custom ViewEngine using Razor engine to select Masterpage dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I´m trying to create my Custom ViewEngine with Razor...
My code is based on [jfar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog/1844916#1844916), the only difference I´m using Razor engine...

I have 2 "masterpages" :

- _Admin.cshtml
- _Modal.cshtml

And the FindView method from my custom ViewEngine :

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
{            
    if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, "_Modal", useCache);
    return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, "_Admin", useCache);
}
```

Debugging that, the *ViewEngineResult*.View is always null, and the generated view is always the same, no matter the masterpage...

If I force **usecache = false**, it returns the view, but I got that error:

> The view at '~/Views/Car/Index.cshtml'
>   must derive from ViewPage,
>   ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or
>   ViewUserControl.

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Car/Index.cshtml' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.]
   System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +306227
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a single cache for 2 different kinds of requests. While it does not directly address your question, take a look at the following post that discusses a similar problem: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

For the exception, could you post the stack trace?