# make controller actions' "return partialview()" automatically link to a "_partialview.cshtml" in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm writing a page in MVC3, and there are a few places where I want to request a page in ajax and from the url bar too.

If the request is a full pagerequest I want the Action to render "Example.cshtml" which is a full view.
But is the request is an ajax request I would only want to render the "_Example.cshtml" which is a partial view.

My code is

```
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_Example");
    }
    return View();
```

but since the MVC3 is all about conventions and that everything is reconfigurable, I would like to able to write

```
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    return View();
```

and still load the "_Example.cshtml" if it's a partial view.
I name "_Something.cshtml" all my partial views anyway so wouldn't it be cleaner if I could just call PartialView(); ?

Please tell me that this is possible. And tell me how.

EDIT:

I still want to be able to make the partialviews different from views, so switching the masterpage would be enough for only a few cases.

I would like to do something like overloading the default path to look for partialviews, like:

```
PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {  
    "~/Views/{1}/_{0}.ascx",               
};
```

but this affect PartialView("Example") to use _Example.cshtml too, which is undesirable.

EDIT:

An other thing I tried is to overload the controller's PartialView() and PartialView(object model) methods, but they cannot be overridden neither can I find a proper way to find which action were they called from.

Comment: You may explain by example what you trying to achieve and seems you stuck in partial view only. Maybe there is a better way out from this scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/03/02/Progressive-enhancement-in-MVC-3-with-the-help-of-custom.aspx)? It may help with what you are looking for.

Comment: This is awesome, made me rethink my whole app logic.
I will accept this one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pretty substantial answer on this one: 
[Simple ASP.NET MVC CRUD views opening/closing in JavaScript UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843894/simple-asp-net-mvc-crud-views-opening-closing-in-javascript-ui-dialog/1844916#1844916)

Basically you adjust the view engine to open full "master themed" views for regular requests and then return the view, but with an empty master, when the request is done via ajax.

Comment: thanks for this answer, although I like your solution, I would still want to use 2 separate cshtmls for the views and partial views, and not just switch the masterpage.
I'll update my main question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class AjaxResultActionFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            result.ViewName = "_" + result.ViewName;
            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }

}
```

This will append a "_" infront of the ViewName that MVC tries to resolve if the IsAjaxRequest returns true.

All you need to do now is to decorate either your actions or the controller with this attribute:

```
    [AjaxResultActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Now, I wrote this on the fly, so in this version it only works when you actually pass the ViewName into the `return View()` statement.

With some debugging and more time though, I'm sure this could be fixed :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's still not what I'm trying to achieve. If I need to declare the view explicitly I might as well declare it with an underscore. And I need to write an if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) to my controller for additional server logic, so putting it out in an attribute helps me little.

Comment: well, if you already need to write extra logic in the if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) - why can't you simply provide the viewname there? Why all the extra work?